# Why did the pin/ unpin options disappear from Docky?

Tags: linux-mint, docky

I am using Docky on Mint 19 Tara. I have really liked using Docky, but recently I noticed the option to pin/ remove apps from the dock has disappeared. This happened right around the time I was customizing my theme. Luckily I had set a restore point with timeshift. I restore my system to the point prior to making my changes. However, the options to pin and unpin on Docky are still not available.

Any thoughts?